# Can't find mac address of my wireless adapter using terminal from kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I need mac address of the wireless adapter for use it in reaver 4 bruth Force attack
I tried ip addr but i cant understand if the right address is the 1st or the 2nd

Comment: It may be easier if we see what you see. Consider [edit]ing and posting the output of `ip addr`. You can obfuscate some things (e.g. `123.xx.xx.xx` for IP address or `aa:bb:00:11:yy:zz` for MAC address). Which exact part of this output do you refer to as "the 1st address"? "the 2nd address"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ip addr` as you suggested.

Looking at the output on my own Kali Machine:

Ignore the first one (loopback address)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Use the second one or one like it for IPv4. My adapter is Ethernet and yours is wireless so it will have a different name.

```
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:xx:xx:ec:2f:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.xx.xxx/24 brd 192.168.xx.xxx scope global dynamic noprefixroute
```

Ignore the non-connected IPv6

```
eth0   valid_lft 1283sec preferred_lft 1283sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feec:2fb2/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So in the output look for the section with you IP address and there you will see the MAC address as above.

You also may need to be sure the wireless card you have in the Kali machine has drivers for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following shell script to get the interface with its mac address:

```
#!/bin/bash
for iface in /sys/class/net/*
do
    mac=$(<"$iface/address")
    echo "$iface: $mac"
done
```